# I have a binary search tree and I want to copy the nodes to an array with inorder (recursive function)

Tags: c

Hi I have a BST binary search tree

```
typedef struct Treenode *SearchTree;
struct  Treenode
{
    int Element;
    SearchTree Left;
    SearchTree Right;
};
```

and I want to create a function

```
FillArray(int sizeoftree, tree, int array[])
```

And I want to use an array and 
copy the nodes of the tree in the array.
How can I do this? the following code does not work.
I tried:

```
int FillArray(int a,SearchTree T,int arr[])
{
    if (T==NULL) 
    {   
       return 0; 
    }
    else
    { 
       FillArray(a,T->Left,arr);   
       arr[a]=T->Element;
       a++; 
       FillArray(a,T->Right,arr);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: I think he wants somebody to write the code for him, which most probably will happen. But I agree with you, needs more context.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your function `FillArray` is only modifying its argument `a`, which is not visible to its caller, since argument passing in C is by value. You will need some way to have the recursive calls tell the spot in `arr` to which to add the elements. One simple way to do this would be to add a parameter, say, `index` that gives the first index in `arr` to which to add an element, and return from `FillArray` the number of elements added so that you can properly update `index` after calling `FillArray` recursively and to return the total number of elements added.

Answer (score 1):

`FillArray` is declared as returning an `int`, but you do not have a return value in the `else` case.

You can use this return value to denote the number of elements filled in; this way, you know where to place the current element in-order.

```
int FillArray(int a, SearchTree T, int arr[]) {
    int count = 0;

    if (T) {
        count += FillArray(a, T->Left, arr);
        arr[a + count++] = T->Element;
        count += FillArray(a + count, T->Right, arr);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you want to return something other than `a`, considering the `+=`s. Or perhaps you want to set `a` to the returned value instead, and return `a` in the null case?

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I am clearly confusing using `a` as an offset or using `a` as number of elements.  That's quite fixable...

Answer (score 0):

gotta pass a by reference

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C.  Pass by pointer would work, though.

Comment: i knew that - since this is clearly homework I thought a clue was better than an exact answer

Comment: Hmm.  I guess it probably is homework -- I didn't think of that at first.  Oh well...